# Configure Wildfly ManagedExecutorService behavior

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, wildfly

The Wildfly ManagedExecutorService behaves very unintuitively to the extend that I suspect the behaviour to be a bug (Wildfly 9, for what it's worth): it spawns `core-size` threads, which it then uses to process the `queue-size`'d queue. Even if `max-size` is set, additional threads are not spawned, no matter how much work is in the queue.

That is, until the queue is completely full, at which point up to `max-size` threads are spawned, but because by then the queue is so full, the newly spawned threads usually can't work it off before jobs get lost due to a maxed out queue.

Normal executor services instead tend to spawn `max(max-size, available work)` threads, in other works, they spawn additional threads if max-size isn't reached if there is additional work available.

But I have been unable to configure the `managed-executor-service` subsystem to provide such a behavior (while still having a job queue). The only alternative seems to be to set core-size to max-size, which is silly. Any hints ?

Comment: This may have something to do with how the `ThreadPoolExecutor` works:  If corePoolSize or more threads are running, the Executor always prefers queuing a request rather than adding a new thread.
If a request cannot be queued, a new thread is created unless this would exceed maximumPoolSize, in which case, the task will be rejected.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to change that behaviour. Were this pure Java, I could easily subclass ThreadPoolExecutor to get the behaviour I want, but I'm guessing that isn't possible in this case.